# Can't get response from Angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-factory

I have a factory:

```
.factory('CompanyRolesResource', function($resource, FdConfig) {
    return $resource(FdConfig.routes.companyRoles);
})
```

And I have a function that use this factory:

```
ctrl.saveCompanyRole = function(companyRole) {
    return CompanyRolesResource.save({}, companyRole).$promise.then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        });
    };
```

In Chrome DevTools I see that response is data like `{status: 200, data: {...}}`. But in `console.log` I just see:

```
Resource
$promise: Promise
$$state: Object
__proto__: Object
$resolved: true
```

Where is my `data`? I can't find it also inside of `$promise` and `$$state`.

**UPD:**

I get right response when I use this way:

```
   $http({
        url: FdConfig.routes.companyRoles,
        method: "POST",
        data: companyRole
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

But my `console.log(response)` in factory returns `undefined`.

Comment: can you create a sample plunker reproducing this? maybe just have a JSON locally being called as API..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access your data from `$resource` directly as it is retrieved from server asynchronously. This means that your data isn't yet loaded when you try to access it. What you need to do is to supply callback for `$resource` action.

Starting from **Angular 1.2**, `$resource` provides you `$promise` for each action which you can use to retrieve your data when it's loaded:

```
CompanyRolesResource.save({}, companyRole).$promise.then(function (response) {
    // do whatever you want with your response.data here
});
```

Comment: but `response.data` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`Resource` is your data object. When you use $resource, you don't get the response as (status, data, headers, config) Object. You will directly get the response (your expected response data)

Answer (score 1):

It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

Under the hood, the ngResource API uses [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to copy the server data to the empty reference. **If the data is not a JavaScript object, nothing will be copied.**

In the case of the `.save` action method, if an array is returned, a `$resource:badcfg` error will be thrown.

> #### Error: $resource:badcfg
>
> #### Response does not match configured parameter
>
> #### Description
>
> This error occurs when the [$resource service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) expects a response that can be deserialized as an array but receives an object, or vice versa. By default, all resource actions expect objects, except `query` which expects arrays.
>
> To resolve this error, make sure your `$resource` configuration matches the actual format of the data returned from the server.
>
> For more information, see the [$resource API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) reference documentation.
>
> [— AngularJS $resource:badcfg Error Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg)